# Plugins effecting layout & login

Tags: plugins, login, debug

I've been working on this issue by myself for a week, and I feel like I'm at my wit's end. Need some advice on what to try next.

The issue is that [my site](http://www.cefgreenville.com) has the white screen of death (no login) when either the WordPressImporter plugin is turned on, or the plugin [Members Access][3]. This is not the only issue though.

Also when either or both of these plugins are turned on, the css for my site is messed up. The nav is pulling in completely wrong, and certain areas have incorrect fonts. This leads me to believe there's more of an issue than two plugins fighting over a js file.

When I turned on the debug in wp-config, I get the following error:

```
Notice: add_option was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.3 with no alternative available. in /mnt/stor1-wc2-dfw1/469547/756542/www.cefgreenville.com/web/content/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3497
```

Any suggestions as to what I should try next?

Also, two notes: I didn't build this website, I'm just managing it. And the issue was present before I upgraded WordPress and all my plugins. I updated in hopes there was a bug fix in one of the apps, but updating has changed absolutely nothing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the `Notice error` is related to the problem with the layout and the css, but as it is the only information you are giving, I answer to it; anyway is an important error you should fix. That error means that you are using [`add_option` function somewhere with an invalid parameter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option#Parameters), exactly with a parameter that was deprecated in WordPress 2.3 and there is not alternative for that parameter. So, the only thing you can do is search and find where `add_option` is being used in such invalid way and update the code to be valid up to the WP version you are using.

You may wonder how to search and fine where `add_option` is used incorrectly. It is not in any file of WordPress file. You could start to deactivate all plugins to see if the problem is in the theme. If it is not in the theme, then start to activate the plugins, one by one, until you find the plugin which files you should check for the invalid use of `add_option`; check them.

You could do also a [debug backtrace](http://php.net/manual/es/function.debug-backtrace.php) if you feel comfortable doing it or use [any of the plugins that do it](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/backtrace).

**Update**: I just noticed that you already know the plugins that are causing the problem. Update them to latest version. If you are using the latest version already, you will have to check for the invalid use `add_option` function and fix it, or contact with the developers of the plugins to fix them for you.